# Is there a way to send the result message to slack when we use the command line to run Katalon's test?

Tags: command-line, katalon-studio

Is it possible to send the Katalon's test result to slack when we are using command line?

I have created the integration for slack inside the Katalon-Studio and it is working fine, but when I tried to execute that test using command-line, the test is running, but the result is not sending to slack.

```
katalon -noSplash  -runMode=console -consoleLog -noExit -projectPath="C:\Users\test\Katalon Studio\Web.Portal\test.prj" -retry=0 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/New Test Suite" -executionProfile="default" -browserType="Chrome"
```

I expected to receive the same message that I've received when I executed the tests through Katalon-Studio.

eg.

Summary execution result of test suite: Test Suites/New Test Suite

Total test cases: 1

Total passes: 1

Total failures: 0

Total errors: 0

Total skipped: 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is Katalon Plugins

To test suite in console mode and you want Katalon to send a summary report to Slack,
You need to add one more parameter -apiKey into your command as well.
To get an API Key, you can access the store (https://store.katalon.com), log in with your account then navigate to the Setting page to add a new apiKey.

Example in CMD mode

```
./Katalon\ Studio.app/Contents/Ms/katalon --args -runMode=console -projectPath="/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/QA-katalon/kyy.prj" -reportFolder=“Reports” -reportFileName=“report” -retry=0 -testSuitePath=“Test Suites/Employees” -browserType=“Chrome” -apiKey=“de544cef-a56b-4eb5-a051-391bc0537b59(your key)”
```

Find more details here >  https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/slack-plugin-integration.html#obtain-slack-legacy-token

Comment: Thanks @lahimadhe ! That's on the spot.